# What am I missing to get GRASS 7.6 tools to run in QGIS 3.4.4 Processing (linux)?

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, qgis-processing, linux

I can't seem to get any GRASS 7.6.0 algorithms to run inside QGIS 3.4.4 Processing toolbox on Arch Linux (kernel 4.20.8).

[image: grass 7 algorithm error in qgis 3]

I have GRASS installed at /opt/grass. Launches fine standalone with tools working and such.

I have gdal and gdal-grass plugin 2.3.2 installed.

```
ogrinfo --formats | grep -i grass                                                                                                                              
OGR_GRASS -vector- (ro): GRASS Vectors (5.7+)
```

I compiled QGIS with the following GRASS cmake options just to be sure even though the first compile without them says it found GRASS 7 in /opt/grass regardless.

```
-DWITH_GRASS7=ON \
-DGRASS_PREFIX7=/opt/grass \
-DGRASS_INCLUDE_DIR7=/opt/grass/include
```

And inside QGIS **Settings > Options > System (tab) > Current Environment Variables** there are some bold variables:

```
GISBASE = /opt/grass
GRASS_PAGER = cat
```

The GRASS Plugin works where it can open mapsets and run tools. QGIS Browser can see and load GRASS Datasets **but Processing won't launch GRASS algorithms**.

---

*I found a 3 year old bug report filed by myself at https://issues.qgis.org/issues/13072 but I'm not sure if it's a regression and needs to be re-opened.*

Comment: Was a bug and has been fixed with QGIS release 3.6.0, voted to close